# sort alphabetically more select options

Tags: select, alphabetical

I have a problem with the select option. I need to sort in alphabetical order different select options (with text and auguali value option). I found an interesting script that seems to work only for a single option does not multiple select. Is there a way to sort each select? For example, click to select the ordering but now overlap the option.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var options = $('select option');
    var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
        return {
            t: $(o).text(),
            v: o.value
        };
    }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
        return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
    });
    options.each(function(i, o) {
        console.log(i);
        o.value = arr[i].v;
        $(o).text(arr[i].t);
    });
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/all2aller/hhe5s/)**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that way you get ALL option from ALL selects. This is why you'll have a lot of duplicates.

You have to iterate on each select and sort only his options.

Furthermore you can use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare two strings.

```
$('button#sort').click(function () {
    $('select').each(function () {
       var options = $(this).children('option');
        options.sort(function (optionA, optionB) {
            return optionA.value.localeCompare(optionB.value);
        });
        $(this).empty().append(options);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPrUN/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code try to sort every option in DOM, you need to sort each select individually.

You may insert your code into a function and use a unique identifier for each select, here is a working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <head>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.button').click(function() {
            sortSelect('prima');
        })
        $('.button_2').click(function() {
            sortSelect('seconda');
        })

        function sortSelect( selectId ) {
            var options = $('select#'+selectId+' option');
            var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
                return {
                    t: $(o).text(),
                    v: o.value
                };
            }).get();
            arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
                return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
            });
            options.each(function(i, o) {
                console.log(i);
                o.value = arr[i].v;
                $(o).text(arr[i].t);
            });
        };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="prima">
        <option value="uno">uno</option>
        <option value="due">due</option>
        <option value="tre">tre</option>
    </select>
    <select id="seconda">
        <option value="uno">uno</option>
        <option value="due">due</option>
        <option value="tre">tre</option>
    </select>
    <button class="button">Ordina la prima select</button>
    <button class="button_2">Ordina la seconda select</button>
</body>
```